# ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

i have a problem, i want to scrape all data-value, but script is scraping only first so i change find to find_all and im getting error.
Hopefully someone can help me.

script:

```
import bs4
import lxml
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link=('www.site.com')

def Data():
   a=soup.find_all("div",{'class':'selector'})     
   b=a.find_all("li").attrs.get("data-value", None)  
   return b
```

and here is website code

```
<div class="selector">
```

Comment: The answer is in the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is exactly what error message is saying you are treating a list as a single element

```
import bs4
import lxml
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link=('www.site.com')

def Data():
    output = []

    #find_all returns a list so use find in a

    a=soup.find("div",{'class':'selector'})     
    b=a.find_all("li")
    for element in b:
        link = element.attrs.get("data-value", None)  
        output.append(link)

    return output
```

Comment: its still scrapping only first data-value

Comment: @DemonsAreHere4000 i have edited the answer to get what you want